# Neo4j APOC Error: Failed to invoke procedure (Access is denied)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("
    match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix'
    return m.name",
"results.csv",{})
```

> Error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
>
> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.csv.query`: Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: results.csv (Access is denied)

I have installed Neo4j on Windows

- Neo4j community version 3.2.6
- Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

It is file write permission issue for user Neo4j. You need to change the path of file as shown below:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("match (m:Movie)
    where m.name='Matrix'
    return m.name",
"/Users/Username/Documents/Neo4j/results.csv",{})
```

Important:

Make sure that you have added following line in "neo4j.conf" file:

```
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

The "neo4j.conf" file in windows is located at:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition
```

Also, edit and uncomment `#dbms.directories.plugins=plugins` as given below:

```
dbms.directories.plugins=C:/Program Files/Neo4j CE 3.2.6/plugins
```

If " #dbms.directories.plugins=plugins" is not present in your "neo4j.config" file, then you have to add this line

I am assuming that you already have downloaded the latest plugin from "https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/3.2.3.5" and placed in your plugin directory that is "C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.6\plugins"